# Why does'nt my mockMvc submit any content?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm trying to optimize an example that I've got from the internet step by step. So I started with the Unit tests. What I want is to write a Unit test with SpringBoot and Mockito like the last example as here https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/.

In my code I have a controller, a DAO and a service. I would like to Unit test 2 methods of my controller e.g. the one with POST and the one with PUT. But somehow the content is'nt submitted.

the controller's method I want to Unit-Test:

```
@PostMapping("/article")
public ResponseEntity<Void> addArticle(@RequestBody Article article, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    boolean isArticleAdded = articleService.addArticle(article);

    if (isArticleAdded == false) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(builder.path("/article/{id}").buildAndExpand(article.getArticleId()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@PutMapping("/article/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Article> updateArticle(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Article article) {
    boolean isArticleUpdated = articleService.updateArticle(id, article);

    if (!isArticleUpdated) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Article>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    article.setArticleId(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<Article>(article, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the corresponding methods in the service:

```
@Override
public synchronized boolean addArticle(Article article){
            if (articleDAO.articleExists(article.getTitle(), article.getCategory())) {
                return false;
            } else {
                articleDAO.addArticle(article);
                return true;
            }
}


@Override
public boolean updateArticle(Integer articleID, Article article) {
    if (articleDAO.articleExists(article.getTitle(), article.getCategory())) {
        return false;
    } else {
        articleDAO.updateArticle(articleID, article);
        return true;            
    }
}
```

the code in the repository that I've optimized:

```
@Override
public void addArticle(Article article) {
    articleRepo.save(article);

}

@Override
public void updateArticle(int articleID, Article article) {
    articleRepo.findById(articleID)
               .map(artcl -> {
                               artcl.setTitle(article.getTitle());
                               artcl.setCategory(article.getCategory());
                               return articleRepo.save(artcl);
                              })
               .orElseGet(() ->  articleRepo.save(article));
}
```

and my tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ArticleController.class)
public class WeblayerTests {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WeblayerTests.class);

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ArticleService articleServ;


@Test
public void testUpdateArticles() throws Exception {
    Article article = new Article(2, "Spring Boot and Docker", "Docker");
    when(articleServ.updateArticle(2, article)).thenReturn(true);


    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/article/2").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                                                                .content(asJSONString(article)))
             .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
             .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}

@Test
public void testAddArticles() throws Exception {
    Article article = new Article(2, "Spring Boot and Docker", "Docker");
    when(articleServ.addArticle( article)).thenReturn(true);

    log.info("the JSON-String: {}", asJSONString(article));    
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/articles").content(asJSONString(article)))
             .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
             .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}

public static String asJSONString(final Object obj) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

but somehow the tests are failing because the content-body is not submittet. On the console I get the following requests:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = POST
  Request URI = /articles
   Parameters = {}
      Headers = []
         Body = <no character encoding set>
Session Attrs = {}


MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = PUT
  Request URI = /article/2
   Parameters = {}
      Headers = [Accept:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
         Body = <no character encoding set>
Session Attrs = {}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you for helping

Comment: Please try to provide a minimize example so that it can be understand easily.

Comment: What do you mean by minimize example?

Comment: Check [mre]. Basically a code snippet you can copy and paste of the question into your IDE. Its should be executable and show the problem you are having. Also try to minimize it by removing unrelated parts from it.

Comment: the code that I've submitted is minimal as possible, to understand my problem. The code spnippets look weird but  are simple. Basically I've implemented an app which manages some articles (Entity). Then I have a JPA-Repo which stores Articles and update them by ID. On top of the Repo I've a DAO which triggers the storage and finally a Service which manage the Saving and the update of articles.  Finally a controller which dispatches the HTTP-Request. The controller is the one I want to Unit-Test with Mockito.I don't know how to simplify it again. You could tell me which info you need.Thanks

Comment: Try adding .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) to the mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/articles")